# How Long is Entry in Singapore Usually?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, singapore, tourism, british, tourist

I’m a British Citizen.  How long is the standard default tourist entry for into Singapore?  Or how long can I usually stay for on these trips?

I cannot find this detail pretty much on gov.uk nor on the main Singapore sources.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Singapore ?

Answer (score 6):

TIMATIC states :

> > Singapore - Destination Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> > Visa Exemptions
>
> Passengers with a British passport with nationality "British Citizen"
> for a maximum stay of 90 days. Additional Information
>
> > Extension of stay possible.
>
> Expectant mothers visiting Singapore for the purpose of delivering
> their child in Singapore must apply for a Visit Pass prior to their
> visit. The Visit Pass can be applied for at [www.ica.gov.sg](http://www.ica.gov.sg) (Apply for
> Visit Pass). Applications take 4 to 6 weeks to process. A Visit Pass
> is not required for nationals of Singapore or residents of Singapore
> holding a Re-entry Permit issued by Singapore.
>
> > Warning
>
> Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.